# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I am making some unit testing. but when i want to run that unit test it gave me error like this

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)"

what i am doing wrong?

this is my gradle. i wonder if i add wrong dependency into it, please help me :'(

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.androidjetpacksubmission1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug{
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
    implementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    implementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:3.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner'
    androidTestImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '3.1.0'
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:3.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
}
```

and this is my unit test code

```
package com.example.androidjetpacksubmission1.ui.detail

import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import com.example.androidjetpacksubmission1.data.entity.TvShowEntity
import com.example.androidjetpacksubmission1.data.repository.RemoteRepository
import com.example.androidjetpacksubmission1.network.Network
import com.example.androidjetpacksubmission1.network.NetworkListener
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.verify


class DetailTvShowViewModelTest : NetworkListener {
    override fun onSuccess(msg: String) {
    }

    override fun onFailure(msg: String?) {
    }

    @get:Rule
    var executorRule = androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    private lateinit var detailTvShowViewModel: DetailTvShowViewModel
    private lateinit var remoteRepository: RemoteRepository
    private lateinit var observer: Observer<*>
    private val tvShowTitleExample = "Jumanji: The Next Level"

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        observer = mock(Observer::class.java)
        remoteRepository = RemoteRepository(Network.routes())
        detailTvShowViewModel = DetailTvShowViewModel(remoteRepository,tvShowTitleExample)
        detailTvShowViewModel.networkListener = this
    }

    @Test
    fun getDetailMovie() {
        detailTvShowViewModel.getDetailTvShow().observeForever(observer as Observer<in TvShowEntity>)

        detailTvShowViewModel.fetchDetailTvShow()

        verify(observer).onChanged()
    }
}

private fun <T> Observer<T>.onChanged() {

}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it seems to be related to the InstantTaskExecutorRule, but I haven't yet figured it out...